# delete old values of a table and update the table with results of same query

Tags: sql

My question is to simple, but I can't find out a way to delete old values of a table and update same table with results of same query.

**UPDATE**

The query is an SELECT on Table A, and the results be Table B. And nothing on Table B different of the result of last query on Table A.

I have a very big table, and I need to process the records and create a new table regularly. The old values of this table are not important, only the new ones.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: What have you tried?  Could you give an example of what you want (before-after)?

Comment: too much information missing, starting with what RDBMS and version you are using

Comment: Are you saying you want to delete some records and then insert those same records into the same table?  What would be the point of that?

Comment: I want query on Table A, and the results be Table B. And nothing on Table B different of the result of last query on Table A.

Comment: Do you want to delete all from table B and then write another query that inserts into table B based on table A?

Comment: its really confusing. what is before and after?

Comment: Yes Kyra. All these in one query!

Comment: Table A is very very big. I need Table B with data processed to a report on HTML.

Comment: are you sure you want 1 single query for insert and delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about a view? If you only need table B to query on. You said you have a select on table A. Lets say your select is `SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE X = Y`. Then your statement would be

```
CREATE VIEW vwTableB AS 
   SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE X = Y
```

And then instead of querying tableB you would query vwTableB. Any changes to the data in table A would be reflected in the view so you don't have to keep running a script yourself.

This was the data in vwTableB would be kept updated and you wouldn't have to keep deleting and inserting into the second table.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a temporary table to store results you are working with, if you only need it for one session.  it will automatically be dropped when you sign out.

you didn't say what db you are using, but try this

```
create temp tableB AS select * from tableA
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I need it to more time, because an aplication will query on the result table. It will be smaller and faster to query on.